# Elasticsearch/Kuromoji: How to Use Kuromoji with Unidic

Tags: elasticsearch, kuromoji

Elasticsearch 1.7

We would like to test Kuromoji with Unidic on Elasticsearch.
Compiling kuromoji gives me a few jars with different dictinaries.

Is there a simple way to replace the ipadic-based-kuromoji with the unidic-based-kuromoji?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the situation any more insightful with Elasticsearch 2.2? E.g., https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/analysis-kuromoji-tokenizer.html ?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the [cmecab-java](https://github.com/takscape/cmecab-java) project as a guide to implement an Elasticsearch wrapper to use unidic-kuromoji (from [here](https://github.com/atilika/kuromoji)). There are older commits from the cmecab-java project which contain lucene plugin wrappers which need to be adjusted for an Elasticsearch-plugin.

Answer (score -1):

tokosh

I think it is no simple way to replace.

See : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-4056
Lucene Kuromoji still has open issue about it.